# nginx service prevents IP leaks ssl certificate

Tags: security, nginx, ssl, haproxy

I use Nginx `ssl_reject_handshake on;` to refuse direct IP access, so as not to leak my origin site certificate, and the server only opens port 443. For this I created a server:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl reuseport default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl reuseport default_server;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    include nginxconfig/block/access-cdn-ip.conf;
    http2 on;
    ssl_reject_handshake on;
}
```

It works fine in https mode, but I noticed that my nginx service is still scanned on the censys website, it is via:`http://ip:443/`,It got the Nginx error page `The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port`.

For this reason, I configured the IP blocking rule `include nginxconfig/block/access-cdn-ip.conf;` in the server to only allow CDN access, but it did not take effect.
Also is there any way to block access via "http://ip:443/"?

When I use haproxy,`bind :::443 v4v6 ssl strict-sni crt /etc....`,As long as the strict-sni field is configured, any access through IP will be blocked. How to configure Nginx?
I use the haproxy service, censys cannot scan my 443 port, it does not know what server my 443 port is, but nginx knows that it is an Nginx server because of the error page it returns.

Comment: Your question is not really about programming. Other sister sites of us may be more appropriate (links on top right icon). Just set default server with self-signed certificate (or no certificate), so that only precise server names will hit the virtual server configuration (and so the certificate). So you should configure actual server as virtual server with precise name/aliases.

Comment: Using a self-signed certificate and using `ssl_reject_handshake`, the results are the same, you can pass `http://ip:443`Get the error page of Nginx, so it can be judged that the service on port 443 is Nginx.

Answer (score 2):

ok,Listen to the ssl traffic on port 443 to deny access from IP, but when accessing this port through http, you will get a 400 error. In fact, it corresponds to the 497 error of nginx. The solution is to redirect the 497 error to 444.

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl reuseport default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl reuseport default_server;
    error_page 497 = /bad;
    http2 on;
    ssl_reject_handshake on;
    location = /bad {
        return 444;
    }
}
```